# How to prevent my earphones from falling out when I wear the helmet?

Tags: headphones

I have [these earphones](http://en-in.sennheiser.com/stereo-ear-headphones-earphones-mx-170).

[image]

They fall off my ears when I wear the helmet for riding on the scooter. What can I do to prevent them from falling? Normally also they keep on falling off.

Comment: Is it because your helmet pinching the cord against your skin, and when your head or helmet moves a bit, your earphones get pulled off? Or do your earphones tend to fall off even when you are not wearing a helmet?

Comment: @fuzzy_onesie actually I don't have the cloth bud covers, if they matter here. Yes, the earphones keep on falling g out even normally.

Comment: It's cause they're not plug earphones, so if your ears aren't big enough or bigger than the earphones they're gonna keep falling out cause there's nothing in your ear that can somewhat hold them in place. **plug earphones to the rescue**

Comment: @xPeke what are plug earphones?

Comment: [This](http://www.jakartanotebook.com/images/products/42/132/3134/2/sound-magic-portable-in-ear-plug-earphone-pl18-black-2.jpeg) See how their design makes them a more *secure "grip"/holding* to your ear by being a bit more deep into your ear canal. They're good if you plan in doing any activity that involves moving around.

Comment: Better known as in-ear headphones ;) @xPeke

Comment: I've always known them as plug earphones @Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix that wouldn't take up more room in your helmet could be to wrap a rubber band around your head at ear level, pushing the speakers into the lug in your ear.

For everyday use without a helmet you could do the same with a headband maybe? As a rubber band may not be comfortable for long periods. I use a headband when running, I run the cable through the top and out the bottom of the headband so if something tugs on the wires the earphones don't get pulled out of my ears.

Answer (score 3):

Having proper fitting headphones is really going to be the least aggravating in my experience. But in the event you want to be warmer, can squeeze a few millimeters in your helmet, and keep earbuds secure, check out the 360 earmuffs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @PoolPartyRenekton said, you first of all need to get earphones that actually fit your ears well (or ear buds). That said in the mean time you can try to pad your existing earbuds with the cloth covers you mentioned, to see if that makes a better fit.

In terms of wearing earphones with a helmet, When I used to wear headphones in a helmet, I found that they came out when I put on my helmet because the helmet would pull the cord down. To counter this, I bunched up some slack near the ear bud before putting on my helmet. You can also try wrapping the cord over and behind your ear, so its harder for them to be pulled out when you put on your helmet. Also, be sure to pull the chin strap as far apart as you can when putting on the helmet, to give your head/ears as much clearance as possible when putting on the helmet.

If all else fails, get a bluetooth headset. I got a Sena headset, and highly recommend everybody who rides consistently to get one.